# Big Endian and Little Endian support for byte ordering

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-c++, endianness

We need to support 3 hardware platforms - Windows (little Endian) and Linux Embedded (big and little Endian). Our data stream is dependent on the machine it uses and the data needs to be broken into bit fields.

I would like to write a single macro (if possible) to abstract away the detail. On Linux I can use `bswap_16`/`bswap_32`/`bswap_64` for Little Endian conversions.

However, I can't find this in my Visual C++ includes.

Is there a generic built-in for both platforms (Windows and Linux)?

If not, then what can I use in Visual C++ to do byte swapping (other than writing it myself - hoping some machine optimized built-in)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On both platforms you have

for `short` (16bit): `htons()` and `ntohs()`

for `long` (32bit): `htonl()` and `ntohl()`

The missing `htonll()` and `ntohll()` for `long long` (64bit) could easily be build from those two. See [this implementation for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/875505/694576).

**Update-0:**

For the example linked above Simon Richter mentions in a comment, that it not necessarily has to work. The reason for this is: The compiler might introduce extra bytes somewhere in the unions used. To work around this the unions need to be packed. The latter might lead to performance loss.

So here's another fail-safe approach to build the `*ll` functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/955980/694576

**Update-0.1:**

From bames53' s comment I tend to conclude the 1st example linked above shall not be used with C++, but with C only.

**Update-1:**

To achieve the functionality of the `*ll` functions on Linux [this approach might be the ' best'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410728/694576).

Comment: Those functions are relatively universal for any OS that understands networks (ie internet). Some most modern OSs.

Comment: Note that their example implementation using `union` is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right the unions should be packed. Thanks for pointing this out. Please see the update to my answer. @SimonRichter

Comment: The issue with using unions like that isn't just packing. In C++ using unions like that is undefined behavior; the optimizer could legally transform `union { int x, y; } u; u.x = 5; return u.y;` into `return 0;`, for example.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting point, which I wasn't aware of, but surely can imagine. You might have any citation for this? @bames53

Comment: [class.union] 9.5/1, or there's a more thorough explanation in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271929/union-for-uint32-t-and-uint8-t4-undefined-behavior).

Comment: Actually, here's a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined

Answer (score 2):

Not the same names, but the same functionality does [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

EDIT: Archived Link -> https://web.archive.org/web/20151207075029/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177(v=vs.80).aspx

_byteswap_uint64, _byteswap_ulong, _byteswap_ushort

Comment: dead link, can you list the name?

Comment: @GrantRostig - edited the answer with an archived link

Comment: new link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/byteswap-uint64-byteswap-ulong-byteswap-ushort?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

htons and htonl (and similar macros) are good if you insist on dealing with byte sex.

However, it's much better to sidestep the issue by outputting your data in ASCII or similar.  It takes a little more room, and it transmits over the net a little more slowly, but the simplicity and futureproofing is worth it.

Another option is to numerically take apart your int's and short's.  So you & 0xff and divide by 256 repeatedly.  This gives a single format on all architectures.  But ASCII's still got the edge because it's easier to debug with.

Comment: Would love to do that, but we don't control the transmission. It is data read in from a special hardware device, and need to handle the bytes from there.