# How to extract a DWORD color variable into its parameters? (decimal type)

Tags: c++, colors, hex, dword

I have the example :

```
unsigned int dwColor = 0xAABBCCFF; //Light blue color
```

- And its parameters from left to right are : **"alpha, red, green, blue"**; each parameter requires two hexadecimal values.
- The maximum value of each parameter is **255**; lowest : **0**

And, how to **extract** then convert all parameters of a DWORD color to decimals?

I like the value range **"0.00 -> 1.00"**.
For example :

```
float alpha = convert_to_decimal(0xAA); //It gives 0.666f
float red = convert_to_decimal(0xBB); //It gives 0.733f
float green = convert_to_decimal(0xCC); //It gives 0.800f
float blue = convert_to_decimal(0xFF); //It gives 1.000f
```

EDIT : I've just seen **union**, but the answerer says it's UB (Undefined Behaviour). Does anyone know the better solution? :)

Comment: And the question is... how to pull each byte from a 32-bit unsigned? or how to convert an `unsigned char` to a `float`?

Comment: @WhozCraig It's good to hear your suggestion. "Gain experience" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use an `union`:

```
union color
{
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned char component[4];
};

color c;
c.value = 0xAABBCCFF;
unsigned char r = c.component[0];
unsigned char g = c.component[1];
unsigned char b = c.component[2];
unsigned char a = c.component[3];
```

If you need to treat it as a float value:

```
float fr = c.component[0] / 255.0f;
float fg = c.component[1] / 255.0f;
float fb = c.component[2] / 255.0f;
float fa = c.component[3] / 255.0f;
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments below, this use of `union` is Undefined Behaviour (UB), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined) from [Luchian Grigore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673730/luchian-grigore).

---

EDIT 2:

So, another way to break a `DWORD`  into components avoiding the `union` is using some bitwise magic:

```
#define GET_COMPONENT(color, index) (((0xFF << (index * 8)) & color) >> (index * 8))
```

But I do not advise the macro solution, I think is better to use a function:

```
unsigned int get_component(unsigned int color, unsigned int index)
{
    const unsigned int shift = index * 8;
    const unsigned int mask = 0xFF << shift;
    return (color & mask) >> shift;
}
```

How it works? Lets supose we call `get_component(0xAABBCCFF, 0)`:

```
shift = 0 * 8
shift = 0

mask = 0xFF << 0
mask = 0x000000FF

0x000000FF &
0xAABBCCFF
----------
0x000000FF

0x000000FF >> 0 = 0xFF
```

Lets supose we call `get_component(0xAABBCCFF, 2)`:

```
shift = 2 * 8
shift = 16

mask = 0xFF << 16
mask = 0x00FF0000

0x00FF0000 &
0xAABBCCFF
----------
0x00BB0000

0x00BB0000 >> 16 = 0xBB
```

*Warning! not all color formats will match that pattern!*

But IMHO, the neater solution is to combine the function with an enum, since we're working with a limited pack of values for the index:

```
enum color_component
{
    A,B,G,R
};

unsigned int get_component(unsigned int color, color_component component)
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case R:
        case G:
        case B:
        case A:
        {
            const unsigned int shift = component * 8;
            const unsigned int mask = 0xFF << shift;
            return (color & mask) >> shift;            
        }

        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("invalid color component");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The last approach ensures that the bitwise operations will only be performed if the input parameters are valid, this would be an example of usage:

```
std::cout
    << "R: " << get_component(the_color, R) / 255.0f << '\n'
    << "G: " << get_component(the_color, G) / 255.0f << '\n'
    << "B: " << get_component(the_color, B) / 255.0f << '\n'
    << "A: " << get_component(the_color, A) / 255.0f << '\n';
```

And here is a [live demo](http://ideone.com/xvu7np).

Comment: That's undefined behaviour AFAIK.

Comment: I'd suggest uint32_t and uint8_t, but the general idea is great:)

Comment: @chris I know about the `UB` of this part, but the fact is that it works in all the compilers I've used BTW, last week I've read a SO answer about this `UB` (from Luchian Grigore I guess) but I'm not able to found it to link :(

Comment: I found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271929/union-for-uint32-t-and-uint8-t4-undefined-behavior).

Comment: @DariuszWawer yes, using `stdint` header could be neat and more portable (avoiding the `UB` part), but I think that I would keep it as is in order to shorten the example, thanks anyway :D